# Python Multi Choice Quiz with a score to count

Tags: python, beginner, quiz

I am trying to make a multi choice quiz with a score to count. This is the first time I've used Python and I'm finding it difficult to make the code work properly. How can I make the code shorter and work better? It tells me my code has an infinite loop, how is that so?

```
#Convert the 0 into a number so we can add scores
score = 0
score = int(score)

#Ask user for their name
name = input("What is your name?")
name = name.title()
print("""Hello {}, welcome to Quiz night! 
You will be presented with 5 questions.
Enter the appropriate number to answer the question
Good luck!""".format(name))

#Question1
print("""What is the term for ‘Maori’ language?
1. Te Rex 
2. Hangi 
3. Hongu 
4. Te Reo""")

answer1 = "4"
response1 = input("Your answer is:")

if (response1 != answer1):
    print("Sorry, that is incorrect!")
else:
    print("Well done! " + response1 + " is correct!")
    score = score + 1

print("Your current score is " + str(score) + " out of 5")

#Question2
print("""What is the Maori term for ‘tribe’ or ‘mob’?
1. Mihi 
2. Iwi 
3. Awi 
4. Hapu""")

answer2 = "2"
response2 = input("Your answer is:")

if (response2 != answer2):
    print("Sorry, that is incorrect!")
else:
    print("Well done! " + response2 + " is correct!")
    score = score + 1

print("Your current score is " + str(score) + " out of 5")

#Question3
print("""What is the term for the formal welcome, where two individuals press their nose together?
1. Hongi 
2. Haka 
3. Hangi 
4. Huka""")

answer3 = "1"
response3 = input("Your answer is:")

if (response3 != answer3):
    print("Sorry, that is incorrect!")
else:
    print("Well done! " + response3 + " is correct!")
    score = score + 1

print("Your current score is " + str(score) + " out of 5")

#Question4
print("""Who is the ‘demi-god’ or the ‘great creator’ who fished NZ out from the sea?
1. Zeus
2. Hercules
3. Maui
4. Maori""")

answer4 = "3"
response4 = input("Your answer is:")

if (response4 != answer4):
    print("Sorry, that is incorrect!")
else:
    print("Well done! " + response4 + " is correct!")
    score = score + 1

print("Your current score is " + str(score) + " out of 5")

#Question5
print("""What is the name for the traditional Maori method of cooking?
1. Roast
2. Hangi
3. Hongi
4. Bake""")

answer5 = "2"
response5 = input("Your answer is:")

if (response5 != answer5):
    print("Sorry, that is incorrect!")
else:
    print("Well done! " + response5 + " is correct!")
    score = score + 1

print("Your total score is " + str(score) + " out of 5")
print("Thank you for playing {}, goodbye!".format(name))
```

Comment: Who is telling to that you have an infinite loop? You haven't even written any loop.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest gain in readability here is to get rid of the duplication. Currently all your strings are hardcoded and you print each of them separately.

We can make life easier by putting the questions, answers and correct answers into some datastructure we can iterate over. In addition, we can bundle these three things together into one `Question` class (which is just a `collections.namedtuple` here, so we can give the fields nice names):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Question = namedtuple("Question", ["question", "answers", "correct_answer"])

GREETING = """Hello {name}, welcome to Quiz night! 
You will be presented with {n} questions.
Enter the appropriate number to answer the question
Good luck!"""

def play_quiz(name, questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        print(question.question)
        for i, answer in enumerate(question.answers, start=1):
            print(f"{i}. {answer}")

        response = input("Your answer is: ")
        if response != question.correct_answer:
            print("Sorry, that is incorrect!")
        else:
            print(f"Well done! {response} is correct!")
            score += 1
        print(f"Your current score is {score} out of {len(questions)}")

    print(f"Your total score is {score} out of {len(questions)}")
    print(f"Thank you for playing {name}, goodbye!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    questions = [Question("What is the term for the ‘Maori’ language?",
                          ["Te Rex", "Hangi", "Hongu", "Te Reo"], "4"),
                 Question("What is the Maori term for ‘tribe’ or ‘mob’?",
                          ["Mihi", "Iwi", "Awi", "Hapu"], "2",
                 ...]
    name = input("What is your name? ").title()
    print(GREETING.format(name=name, n=len(questions)))
    play_quiz(name, questions)
```